# Suggestions for replacing/upgrading exhaust/silencer for a 125cc Motorbike

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust, yamaha

I have a 125cc Yamaha Gladiator SS125, which is about 3 years old. I had my stock air filter (paper-based) removed and installed a K&N conical filter about a year ago. I wanted to know if anyone could suggest any replacement/upgrade that I can do to my exhausts/silencers.

Any help is this direction would be appreciated.

Comment: This question will likely be closed as most will consider it to be shopping-assistance-related, which is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @Roopesh90  Take a tour [here](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) , and re-post your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a free flow exhaust to your system ,Since your bike is carbeuratted, if you have not upjetted your carb to accommodate the increased airflow I bet your engine is running lean that is,  more air less fuel.

This can seriously damage the engine.

To cut costs you can remove the silencer from the cylinder  , remove the catalytic converter and reinstall it. instead of trying to go for a full system exhaust which will cost much more.(all this after upjetting your carb)

Comment: If I make a mistake, it would rather be on the other side. :)

Comment: @You_Shall_Not_Pass , Sorry didnt get you..

Comment: I meant, If i were making a mistake in tuning the carb, i would rather want it to running rich instead of the engine running lean (like in this case, and  particularly if it were a two stroke)  ;)